# IIS Website failed to fetch dynamically imported module

Tags: iis, node-js

When I try to look at my site from the outside with

`http://example.com/{R:1}/page1.html`
I get error failed to fetch dynamically imported module:

`http://example.com/client/index.7e18705d.js`

but when I use

`http://example.com//{R:1}/page878.html`

it works and all the links for flawlessly.

Expected outcome: Site host normally.

Things tried: Different URL rewrite, tried different server, tried rewriting my `index.html` file. Outcome happening: Only works flawlessly from any computer or phone browser with the "//" after the domain name.
Below is `web.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <preConditions>
           <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
             <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
           </preCondition>
       </preConditions>
     </outboundRules>
     <rules>
       <rule name="Localhost to Example Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^.*$" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost:5173" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:0}" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```